# Objective-C: Generic Pointers in practice

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Namaste! How often do you, experienced guys using generic pointers in daily routine and what's the common purpose for generic pointers in cocoa-touch development?

EDIT

> A variable declared as a pointer to void is a generic pointer.

There's such thing. It may be set to an address of any variable type. I just want to know how the people use this kind of pointers in real life coding.

P.S Thank you for down voting.

Comment: What do you mean by "generic pointers"? The `id` type?

Comment: What's a generic pointer? Do you just mean an id?

Comment: Im not sure this question has a definitive answer.  While the dynamic aspect of objective C is nice and flexible, I tend to avoid the use of the generic pointer type id in my own code. Its not that using it is wrong, I just prefer to code to specific classes whenever possible.

id IMO should be reserved for use in situations where it really could be *anything* so you see it used a lot in callbacks and delegates.

Its very flexible but its only needed when its needed.

Comment: @stackmonster It has definitive answer. Sure the generic pointers may be used in real life. Like << >> operators. I just want to know how often this stuff is in use from experienced guys.

Comment: @ Richard J. Ross III A variable declared as a pointer to void.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are fewer and fewer cases where `void*` is appropriate in ObjC. They're still used for some things like context pointers for KVO, but with the addition of ARC they're a pain to use even for that. Basically, if you need to ask when you would use a `void*`, you probably shouldn't use a `void*`. They're a little more common in the callbacks of Core frameworks, again usually for context pointers.

But to the question, "How often do you... [use `void*`] ... in daily routine," the answer is "very seldom, and as little as possible."

Comment: Wish I could upvote twice just for:"Basically, if you need to ask when you would use a void*, you probably shouldn't use a void*."

Comment: @Thank you Rob. Your answer is clear and complete.

Comment: Sorry this is incorrect - a generic pointer in Objective C is id - its not a void pointer thats C.  void pointers are not used in Objective C at all

Comment: The OP explicitly said he was asking about void pointers. While I wish that void pointers were not used in ObjC at all, they are. For examples of context pointers, see addObservrer:forKeyPath:options:context:, beginAnimations:context:, sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:. In addition, there are many routines that reference `void*` for dealing with raw memory, such as encodeArayOfObjCType:count:at:, getBytes:, appendBytes:length:, etc. Then there are particularly tricky ones (from an ARC point of view) like getReturnValue:. As I said, these are not commonly used by beginners, but there are many.